# Overflow happens when word-break breaks a word after each letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

Overflow happens with the following ONLY when word-break breaks a word **after each letter**. This effect happens if the user zooms (CMD +) ridiculously big.

CSS:

```
.turnOnWordBreak {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap:     break-word;

    width:         auto;

    white-space:   normal;
}

.turnOffWordBreak {
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    word-wrap:     normal;

    width:         auto;
}
```

JS:

```
/* turn on/off word break */

wordBreakOn = (function turnOnWordBreak() {

    /*
        .superLongStuff is empty ...
        .turnOnWordBreak and .turnOffWordBreak do all the work
    */
    $('.superLongStuff').removeClass('turnOffWordBreak').addClass('turnOnWordBreak');

})


wordBreakOff = (function turnOffWordBreak() {

    $('.superLongStuff').removeClass('turnOnWordBreak').addClass('turnOffWordBreak');

})

$(document).ready(function() {

    wordBreakOn();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="superLongStuff">
lots and lots of long text
</div>
```

Comment: So, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: How do I stop the overflow even with the breaking after each letter?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: As soon as I get home. Right now I’m at Arlington National Cemetery. In the meantime, I know how to prevent overflow via overflow:hidden. My real question centers on the fact that overflow should never happen with overflow-wrap: break-word and because I have text-align:center on the text in question. Only with gigantic zooming, the centered text starts to move toward its parent <div> and eventually breaks thru